# How to move to next file

Tags: c#

I've searched high and low for days now to figure away to read a directory then edit a text file based off the file names in the directory with each file name replacing a text on a different line. I have came up with the code below but the problem is it changes the text on all lines to the first file name.

```
DirectoryInfo dinfo1 = new DirectoryInfo(path);
FileInfo[] Files1 = dinfo1.GetFiles("*.*");

string text = File.ReadAllText("path/text.txt");

foreach (FileInfo file in Files1)
{
    text = text.Replace("oldtext1", "path" + file.Name);
    text = text.Replace("oldtext2", "path" + file.Name);
    text = text.Replace("oldtext3", "path" + file.Name);

}

File.WriteAllText("path/text.txt", text);
```

Note: I have 100 files in the folder and want to add all 100 files to the text in a first to last order or alphabetical order as new files will be added and I want to keep the order.

Comment: Is your `path` end with `/`? and what is your `oldtext` means?

Comment: Take a look at the [Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx) method to combine paths rather than using string concatenation. It automagically deals with problems like trailing slashes and the like.

Comment: My pah end with / but the path isnt the problem because it executes. Oldtext mean the text in the file that i want to change to the file name.

Comment: So what are you actually trying to do here? Is the idea to replace `oldtext1` with the first filename and `oldtext2` with the second and so on?

Comment: yes thats exactly what Im trying to do Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to replace `oldtext1` with the first filename and `oldtext2` with the second and so forth, then this should be pretty simple:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Files1.Length; i++)
{
    text = text.Replace("oldtext" + (i+1), "path" + Files1[i].Name);
}
```

We are using a regular `for` loop because we want to have an index into the `Files1` array. Then we build the string to be replaced by concatenating `oldtext` with `i+1` and we replace it with the current filename in the array.

So first time through the loop, we replace:

```
oldtext1 => filename1
```

the second time:

```
oldtext2 => filename2
```

and so no:

```
oldtextn => filenamen
```

> Note: I have 100 files in the folder and want to add all 100 files to the text in a first to last order or alphabetical order as new files will be added and I want to keep the order.

Note that the order of files returned by `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` is not guaranteed to be in any particular order. You should use [Array.Sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.sort(v=vs.110).aspx) to sort them before you run the above loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
text.Replace("oldtext1", path + file.Name);
```

After this action, there will be no `oldtext1` can be replaced for the next file name,same to `oldtext2` and `oldtext3`,this is why all lines has been changed to the first file name, I think below code will help you

```
text += file.FullName+Environment.NewLine;
```